# UIScrollView missing touches when transparent

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, jailbreak

I have a zoomable UIScrollView with multiple subviews. The UIWindow it's within has no backgroundColor, neither does the UIScrollView. The scroll view does not recognize touches that don't start on one of the subviews (so zooming/panning doesn't work unless the touch starts on a subview). I'd like the scroll view to remain transparent, but also recognize touches that occur on it's transparent parts. This is for a jailbreak tweak.

If I set a backgroundColor for either the scroll view or the UIWindow, the scroll view gets touches again, but I want them to both be transparent.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using touch event? touch events does not work on UIScrollView.

Comment: I'm not using any touch events.